# List processing in clojure, tail recursion needed

Tags: algorithm, clojure, functional-programming, tail-recursion

Given a sorted list of intervals, e.g. 
`(def lst (list [7 10] [32 35]))`

I need to implement a function that adds a new interval to the list. If the new interval is adjacent to any of those from the list, they should be merged:

```
(= (add-range [1 3] lst)   (list [1 3] [7 10] [32 35]))  ;; prepend left
(= (add-range [1 6] lst)   (list [1 10] [32 35]))        ;; merge left
(= (add-range [11 20] lst) (list [7 20] [32 35]))        ;; merge right
(= (add-range [11 31] lst) (list [7 35]))                ;; merge left and right
```

This is my implementation:

```
(defn add-range
  [range range-list]
  (if (empty? range-list)
    (list range)
    (let
      [lo (first range)
       hi (second range)
       head (first range-list)
       head-lo (dec (first head))
       head-hi (inc (second head))]
        (if (< hi head-lo)
          (cons range range-list)
          (if (= hi head-lo)
            (cons [lo (second head)] (rest range-list))
            (if (= lo head-hi)
              (recur [(first head) hi] (rest range-list))
              (cons head (add-range range (rest range-list)))))))))
```

It works and looks quite elegant too, but the last line contains a recursive call `add-range` which can not be replaced with `recur` because it is not the last call. I'm planning to have long range lists in my application and I don't want to blow up the stack.

How this can be rewritten using the tail recursion? 
Is there another approach to solve the problem? Lazy sequences maybe?

**UPDATE**
The sorted list is actually not required. This can be a set or even an unsorted list, but it would be really nice to do it in a single pass.

Comment: Why not use a sorted-set instead of a list to start with?

Comment: @cgrand, I thought of mentioning that in my answer. We can think of the solution as consisting of two parts, 1) insert range at correct position, 2) collapse neighbouring ranges. The current algo does both steps in a single pass. With a sorted set, the sorting step would be an additional pass, right? I assumed a single pass was preferred.

Comment: @AmithGeorge if you represent your list of ranges as a set from the beginning (since it's a set anyway: you can't have twice the same range in i it) then you have the sort mosty for free. See my answer for an impl.

Comment: @conceptacid my answer (written before your update) uses a sorted set and does not even require a single pass since it has sublinear complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a sorted set you can implement it as:

```
;; first the constructor
(defn ranges [& rs]
  (apply sorted-set-by
    (fn [[from-a to-a] [from-b to-b]]
      (< to-a (dec from-b))) rs))

;; then add-range itself
(defn add-range [ranges [from to :as r]]
  (let [rs (subseq ranges <= [from from] <= [to to])
        ranges (reduce disj ranges rs)]
    (conj ranges
      (let [[from'] (or (first rs) r)
            [_ to'] (or (last rs) r)]
        [(min from from') (max to to')]))))
```

Let's try your tests:

```
=> (def lst (ranges [7 10] [32 35]))
#'user/lst
=> (add-range lst [1 3])
#{[1 3] [7 10] [32 35]}
=> (add-range lst [1 6])
#{[7 10] [32 35]}
=> (add-range lst [11 20])
#{[7 20] [32 35]}
=> (add-range lst [11 35])
#{[7 35]}
```

Addendum #1: `add-range` is O((m + 1) log n) where n is the size of the ranges set and m the number of merged intervals.

Comment: Nice. I think this also handles the input `[3 37]`, which wasn't being handled originally. Regarding my sorting question, there is only an insertion happening and no explicit sorting of all elements.

Comment: Great answer! Elegant solution. Thanks, @cgrand

Answer (score 2):

In my experience making something tail recursive involves passing as arguments all local state. Looking at the algo, it looks like already processed range items is the local state. ie, `final result = (ranges ignored + merged-range + ranges not required to be considered)`.

Consider the following version, it explicitly passes a seq of already processed items.

```
(defn add-range
  [range-obj ranges]
  (loop [processed []
         range-obj range-obj
         remaining (list* ranges)]
    (if (empty? remaining)
      (conj processed range-obj)
      (let [[lo hi] range-obj
            [h-lo h-hi :as head] (first remaining)
            upper-merge-threshold (dec h-lo)
            lower-merge-threshold (inc h-hi)]
        (cond 
          (< hi upper-merge-threshold) (into processed 
                                             (conj remaining range-obj))
          (= hi upper-merge-threshold) (into processed 
                                             (conj (rest remaining) [lo h-hi]))
          (= lo lower-merge-threshold) (recur processed
                                              [h-lo hi]
                                              (rest remaining))
          :else (recur (conj processed head)
                       range-obj
                       (rest remaining)))))))
```

My version accepts a vector and returns a vector. You could modify the relevant code to make it accept a list and return a list.

As for is there a better algorithm, I don't know. I have simply converted your algo to be tail recursive.